# Select SUM from another Select SUM result in mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have one Select SUM command that works:

```
# SIM Orders Pending by Customers for 3101708 IMSI SIMs with 5YY MSISDNs
SELECT accountname AS 'Account Name', 
       IF ((SELECT * FROM 5YYAccounts WHERE 5YYAccounts.accountid = T3101708.accountid) IS NULL , 'N','Y') AS '5YY MSISDN',
       LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(SUM(quantity), 0)),15,' ') AS 'Quantity'
FROM  T3101708
WHERE outputfilereceived IS NULL AND (SELECT * FROM 5YYAccounts WHERE 5YYAccounts.accountid = T3101708.accountid) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY accountname, accountid
ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC;
```

After running this, I get following result:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
| Account Name                    | 5YY MSISDN | Quantity        |
+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
| FCA - SXM - AT&T                | Y          |          48,000 |
| Numerex - AT&T                  | Y          |          34,000 |
| Mytrex Inc. - AT&T              | Y          |          24,000 |
| Honda US - AT&T                 | Y          |          18,000 |
+---------------------------------+------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Based on the result above, I want to SUM the last column by having following Select SUM command:

```
SELECT SUM(
    SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM  T3101708
    WHERE outputfilereceived IS NULL AND (SELECT * FROM 5YYAccounts WHERE 5YYAccounts.accountid = T3101708.accountid) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY accountname, accountid
);
```

For this time, I am getting an error in mySQL:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(quantity)
>       FROM  T3101708
>       WHERE outputfilereceived IS NULL AND' at line 2

What did I code wrong here?

Thank you.
Bobby

Comment: If you need overall sum only - simply remove GROUP BY and excess field(s) from output. If you need overall sum in addition to separate sums use GROUP BY  WITH ROLLUP.

Comment: *What did I code wrong here?* The problem is not related to this query - server starts the citated query fragment from the char where the problem was found, so the problematic point is posessed before the keyword `SELECT`. I think you try to use multi-query with the method which does not allow this.

Comment: Thank you Akina.
Based on your input, I was able to fix my issue.
The solution was simpler than what I originally designed.

SELECT SUM(quantity) AS 'Total'
FROM  T3101708
WHERE outputfilereceived IS NULL AND (SELECT * FROM 5YYAccounts WHERE 5YYAccounts.accountid = T3101708.accountid) IS NOT NULL;

This was the solution that worked.

Thank you.
Bobby